# filter lazy initialized collection

Tags: java, hibernate, filter, lazy-loading

My objects: **user** and **credential** - many to many relationship, however user has a param

I want to get all users with certain param for every credential in a loop

requirement: users have to be loaded in batch.

- simple right?

so i have 3 tables:

```
@Table(name = "CRED")
public class Credential {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name="CRED_ID")     
    Long credentialId;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "credential")
    @BatchSize(size = Search.DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE)
    private Set<UserCredentialMapping> userCredentialMappingSet;  
}

@Table(name = "USER_CRED")
public class UserCredentialMapping {

    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id")
    @ManyToOne
    @Filter(name="paramFilter", condition="param = :param")
    private User user;

    @JoinColumn(name = "cred_id", referencedColumnName = "cred_id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Credential credential;
}

@Table(name = "USER")
public class User  {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name="USER_ID")     
    Long userId;

    @Column(name = "PARAM")
    String param
}
```

i'm making a query in one place and return results:

```
    String hqlQuery =   "select c from UserCredentialMapping m " +
        " inner join m.credential c" +
        " inner join m.user u" +
        " where u.param = :param" +
        " and c.user_id in (:users)" ;

        Session session = getSession();
        //desparetly trying to set filter
        session.enableFilter("paramFilter").setParameter("param", param);

    Query query = session.createQuery(hqlQuery);
    query.setParameterList("users", USERLIST);
    query.setParameter("param", someparam);

    List<Credential> credentialList = (List<Credential>)query.list();
    return credentialList;
```

some processing on each credential in mean time and now i need to get list of users with given param:

```
    for(Credential credential : credentialList){

        //following line makes hibernate query for users
        Iterator<CredentialMapping> mappingIterator = e.getUserCredentialMappingSet().iterator();

        while (mappingIterator.hasNext()){
            UserCredentialMapping userCred = mappingIterator.next();

            User user = userCred.getUser(); 
            DOEVILSTUFFTOINNOCENT(user);
    }
```

My problem is that iterator generates SQL query that gets all users for credential and not all users **with specified param** for credential (in other words filter is not being applied)

Any advise how to make it work?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by adding ManyToMany mapping to Credential class:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
@JoinTable(name = "USER_CRED", 
    joinColumns = { 
        @JoinColumn(name = "CRED_ID") }, 
    inverseJoinColumns = { 
        @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID") })
@Filter(name="param", condition="PARAM = :param")
@BatchSize(size = Search.DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE)
private Set<User> users;
```

i couldn't get it working through UserCredentialMapping...